# Connecting two wires to a DC 12v port on a controller board with 4 pads for a monitor

Tags: dc, wire, 12v, monitor

Sorry, the question was difficult to word. Basically I recently bought a controller board for a monitor and the DC cable I got wasn't correct. So until I get the right part, I just want to test the board and the monitor to see if they work.

When I turn it over, where the DC 12V jack is, there are 4 pads: 2x 12V and 2x Ground. Is there a way I can simply connect a red and black wire just to test?

[Here is an image to explain it further.]

[image: photo of PCB]

All I want to do is connect a red and black wire, which I will connect to step up board, as this will be powered by USB, and supply 12V. (Don't worry, I checked all the amps, and voltages first, and please don't give any alternative ways of doing this.) I just don't want to go ahead and connect two wires and cause something to break.

EDIT: Which ones do I connect to? Both of the 12v and gnd? Or a specific one?

Many thanks.

Comment: Soldering Iron ... ?

Comment: *sigh... * I realise my question probably wasn't very clear so I've edited it. I meant which ones do I connect to? One wire to both 12v and the other to both gnd. Or one wire to one 12v and one wire to one gnd?

Comment: why should we guess without full datsheet?  use 12Vdc input jack + on pin. It could be switched 12V pin for dual source

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 - Here is all I could find online: http://www.vslcd.com/specification/M.RT2281(Without%20Audio).pdf

Comment: so all you have is RT2281 ? with what monitor? and what input?  LCD uses 12V for signals and 12V for LED backlight option and some boards have onboard converter and others interface via CN2 option

Comment: Does your board have a big torroid on top? What is exact P/N?

Comment: It's a bit unlikely that you have correctly evaluated the power requirements for doing this with a step-up converter - did you factor in that it will draw more current at the lower voltage than it will produce at the output, because power is the product of current and voltage, and because there are losses? Claiming to have correctly evaluated that, while asking the question you are asking is a somewhat unusual combination of circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just connect one wire to one of the 12V pad and the other wire to one of the GND pad.

Although there are 2 pads for 12V, the pads are interconnected so it doesn't matter which pad you connect to. Same applies for GND.

Comment: Some boards have torroidal coil with converter, however this PDF shows none and uses external converter

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75, Thanks for the correct info, edited the answer.

Comment: I've marked this as the answer. Thank you @SunnyskyguyEE75 and Electric_90 for your help.

Comment: It seems to have many options for 12V input V with jumper for 5V,3.3V and LVDS may need flat ferrite CM strip on ribbon cable to improve S/N at 1920x1080p from my experience due to SMPS ripple. As I cannot see SMD CM Chokes for dual LVDS GHz signals

Answer (score 1):

do a continuity test with one probe on a known GND pad and probe the unknown pads that show which 2 pads are GND do the same with the 12V line then just solder each wire to the right pad, there might be a reson for the 2 pads but if your just wanting to see everything powers on then there shouldnt be a problem